# Simple background slider with fade

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, fade

I am trying to edit a website. I am an amateur coder and I have the following problem:

Right now, I have a website with a section that has a fixed background. I would like to make that a background with 4 or 5 rotating, fading images each 5 seconds or so. I would know how to do this if the code was indicated in the HTML file, but the background is indicated in the styles css file. Please take a look at the HTML:

```html
<main class="main main-full main-startup" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.7" id="inicio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="opener">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1 style="font-family: sackers" class="hidden-xs">TITLE</h1>
        <h1 style="font-family: sackers; font-size:35px" class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">TITLE</h1>
        <h1 style="font-size:20px">Subtitle</h1>
        <div class="lead-hr wow fadeIn"></div>
        <p class="lead wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Another subtitle.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

And this is the CSS of this respective section:

```
 .main-startup{background:url("../img/bg/startup.jpg") 50% 0 no-repeat;background-size:cover;}
```

I have no idea how to tell the css and html that I want to show a list of different pictures that fade to the next one each 5 seconds. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I have tried the following jquery:

```
<script>
$(function () { 
    var imageArray = ['BG-1.jpg', 'BG-2.jpg', 'BG-3.jpg', 'BG-4.jpg'] 

// on page load
$('#inicio').css({ 'background-image': 'url(/img/slider/' + imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length)] + ')', 'background-size': 'cover' })

// every 10 seconds change to random image name in the array
setInterval(function () { 
    $('#inicio').css({ 'background-image': 'url(/img/slider/' + imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length)] + ')', 'background-size': 'cover' }) 
    }, 10000); 
});
</script>
```

However, it won't work. It still follows the main-startup css code and shows only one background picture. And I don't know how to tell it to ignore that and follow the script I added! Any idea of what I can do?

Comment: you tagged jQuery . Where is your JQ code ?

Comment: use setInterval and add a different class for each interval that correspond to your css

Comment: @MihaiT, I've tagged it so because I thought it might be an option

Comment: @slashsharp, thank you! My knowledge is limited, however. Is there any way you could develop this a little more?

Comment: There are so many ways to make slideshows, like bootstrap carousel or even custom javascript/jQuery . You should know that SO is not a free code making site . We help you develop your pre-existing code. So, try something by-yourself, post here what you have tried and we will help you

Answer (score 0):

this is best example for image slider using html and css please 
try this link [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_rr)

also try this [Link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Simple-Automatic-Image-Slideshow-Plugin-For-jQuery.html)

Comment: `using html and css` and also javascript/jQuery .

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of what you wanted to achieve, hope it helps.

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 1;
  setInterval(function() {
    var banner = $('#inicio').removeClass('banner1 banner2 banner3 banner4 banner5').addClass('banner' + count);
    count++;
    if (count == 6) count = 1;
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.banner1 {
  background: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=banner+1&w=350&h=150') no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.banner2 {
  background: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=banner+2&w=350&h=150') no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.banner3 {
  background: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=banner+3&w=350&h=150') no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.banner4 {
  background: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=banner+4&w=350&h=150') no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.banner5 {
  background: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=banner+5&w=350&h=150') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="main main-full main-startup" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.7" id="inicio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="opener">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1 style="font-family: sackers" class="hidden-xs">TITLE</h1>
        <h1 style="font-family: sackers; font-size:35px" class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">TITLE</h1>
        <h1 style="font-size:20px">Subtitle</h1>
        <div class="lead-hr wow fadeIn"></div>
        <p class="lead wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">Another subtitle.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: I have tried the following jquery:

`<script>
$(function () { 
    var imageArray = ['BG-1.jpg', 'BG-2.jpg', 'BG-3.jpg', 'BG-4.jpg'] 

// on page load
$('#inicio').css({ 'background-image': 'url(/img/slider/' + imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length)] + ')', 'background-size': 'cover' })

// every 10 seconds change to random image name in the array
setInterval(function () { 
    $('#inicio').css({ 'background-image': 'url(/img/slider/' + imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length)] + ')', 'background-size': 'cover' }) 
    }, 10000); 
});
</script>`

Comment: However, it won't work. It still follows the main-startup css code and shows only one background picture. And I don't know how to tell it to ignore that and follow the script I added! Any idea of what I can do?